# Rails: Image upload (WIthout plugin's)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, forms, upload

I have a table which stores information about sauces. Each sauce has an image inside the images assets folder, inside a folder called sauces. All sauces files are named the same;
eg `assets/images/sauces/sauces_piri.png`

All I want to do is basically upload a .png file in the form where the creation takes place, and inside the field of pic_url the name of the image is stored along with the sauces/ so it is directed correctly when I want to display the image.

Currently the administrator has to physically upload the image in the correct position using the domain file management, and also input the "sauces/sauces_name.png" when creating the new sauce.

The form for adding a new sauce :

```
<%= error_messages_for(@sauce) %>
   <table summary="Sauces Form Fields">
    <tr>
     <th><%= f.label(:name,"Sauce Name") %></th>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th><%= f.label(:description, "Description") %></th>
     <td><%= f.text_area(:description, :size => '40x5') %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <th><%= f.label(:heat_level, "Heat Level") %></th>
     <td><%= f.select(:heat_level,{ 1 => "1", 2 => "2", 3 => "3", 4 => "4", 5 => "5"}) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:pic_url, "Picture URL") %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:pic_url) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:title_colour, "Title Colour") %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:title_colour) %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th><%= f.label(:description_colour, "Desc Colour") %></th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:description_colour) %></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

So without using plug-ins such as paperclip how do I enable an image upload which then the file is stored in the correct place, and also in the table field `pic_url` the foldername/filename.png is stored?

Comment: So, where is the question?  Or is it a request to write it?  Make an attempt and post what your are having problems with.

Comment: The question is there. I'll rephrase to make it more obvious.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730212/uploading-files-to-db-rails-3-without-using-external-gems), it might offer some help

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what you are having issues with.  So, I will post a sample form on uploading files.

```
<%= form_for(:uploaded_data_file, :url => upload_files_path(:params => params) ,  :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true } ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Upload" %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :location %>
<% end %>
```

You will have to define the path for the function that will store the image in this example it is called `upload_files_path` and we are passing to it all the `params`.  Then restart the webapp to get the new routes.

In the controller, you can save the file and its details

To get the file name

```
params[:uploaded_data_file][:location].original_filename
```

To get the file itself and save it

```
File.open("where/to/save", "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:uploaded_data_file][:location].read) }
```

To make sure its a .png, you can do some regex checks

```
if(name =~ /.png$/i) # for more than one type do (name =~ /.jpeg$|.png$/i)
```

To do something else look in your `params` and make the desired changes.

For the route to work you can look at http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get :upload_files # will create upload_files_posts_path
  end
end
```

Or

```
match '/upload_files', :to => 'controller_name#method_name' # 'posts#upload_files'
```

Or

```
<% form_tag({:action => 'upload_file'}  #will use the correct controller based on the form
```

Comment: you are on the right lines, is there a way you can specify where the code goes e.g. Model,Controller etc and possible to make it specific for my sauces Model?